# Prove that if $~(n)|m~$ then $~a^m ≡ 1(\mod n)~$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Prove that if $~(n)|m~$ then $~a^m ≡ 1(\mod n)~$

I'm finding this hard for me to prove, I would more than appreciate help with this.

$~\gcd(a,n)=1~$; $~a,n,m∈\mathbb N~$
this is all I'm given, how do I do this?

Thank you very much for all the help

Comment: Are you familiar with Euler's theorem: $a^{\phi(n)}=1\bmod n$?

Comment: Yes but doesn't this mean that I need to prove that phi(n) =m?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $\phi(n)|m$ then we can write $m=d\phi(n)$ for some integer $d$. So what is $a^{m}$?

Comment: I see where you're getting at but in order for this to work i need to get rid of the d, how would i do that?

Comment: $a^m=a^{d\cdot \varphi(n)}=(a^{\varphi(n)})^d\equiv 1^d=1 \mod n$

Answer (score 0):

It folows from the following applied modularly:

- any power of 1 is 1
- $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$

  Reversing the second, we have that, if have an exponent a multiple of $\varphi(n)$ then it can be written with the parenthesized exponent as $\varphi(n)$

Evaluation of the parentheses gives 1 anytime $a$ is coprime to $n$

It then follows from our first rule (exchanging equals sign for congruence) that the new expression is congruent to 1.